# How to ignore (undo) the WM_SETFOCUS for the new window and WM_KILLFOCUS for the old one, keeping the rest of the processing?

Tags: windows, winapi, focus, setfocus

Lets say I have a frame window containing an `EDIT` and a `BUTTON` controls,
I need to keep the focus always on that edit control whenever I click on the button, and continue the normal button click processing altering the edit content (a behavious very similar to the Spin Control buttons).
is there anyway to to achieve this (like to intercept the focus change and prevent it from happening at all or at least undo it) ?

TIA.

I have tried `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` returning `MA_NOACTIVATE` but it didn't work for me, I guest this is because the main frame I work on is already active when I click the button.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `SetFocus(EditHwnd)` in the `OnClick()` handler?

Comment: @AdrianMole, Yes I did, and I was not sure about my decision, but this would be my last resort workaround because I will lose the last cursor position or selection of the `EDIT` control, and I wanted to do action before `WM_SETFOCUS` event happens at all if possible!

Comment: By default, an edit control selects all contents when it gets focused. This behavior can be changed by subclassing the control and handling the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message. Just pass the message to the default edit control procedure and remove the `DLGC_HASSETSEL` flag before returning the value. This will preserve the selection and cursor position across focus changes.

Comment: @IInspectable, it turns out that handling `WM_GETDLGCODE` message and removing `DLGC_HASSETSEL` from the return value is the best solution in this case, it even keeps the last caret position or selection when getting the focus back and I won't need a member variable to store these values.

Comment: Indeed, that's the default behavior of the edit control: It maintains all of its state. My previous comment was slightly inaccurate, though. It's *not* the edit control that performs the selection. It is the dialog manager that does. During (keyboard) input processing, it sends `WM_GETDLGCODE` and adjusts its behavior based on the flags returned by the individual controls. This allows controls to participate in customizing default dialog manager behavior.